# Where do the arrays in my function disappear?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, adodb

I have a controller code:

```
public function chartService(){
    $result["categories"] = array();
    $result["series"] = array(

    $penjualan = $this->db->Execute("select id_tenant, nama_kantin, 
    count(id_penjualan) as jumlah_penjualan, sum(total) as total from 
    kantin_penjualanTenant a join kantin_lokasiKantin b on 
    a.id_kantin=b.id_kantin  group by a.id_tenant,b.nama_kantin");

    while ($row = $penjualan->FetchNextObject(false)) {
        $result["categories"][]=$row->id_tenant;
        $result["nama_kantin"][]=$row->nama_kantin;
        $result["series"][0]=
        array(
                'name' => 'Total Penjualan',
                'data' => array((float)$row->total)
            );
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

When I try to run this code, the result is one array in

```
'data' => array((float)$row->total)
```

But actually, I have 11 data arrays. Why does just one data array show, and not 11?

Comment: What is $penjualan->FetchNextObject(false) statement and why are you passing false in this ? Because according to the function name, you are preventing it from fetching the next object.

Comment: Yes. But can you remove the false there or use true instead of false in FetchNextObject() and then try it. maybe that'll solve it because, as I said earlier, from the function name it looks as if you're preventing it from fetching the next object.

Comment: when i use true instead the query not run

Comment: ok. Can you tell me as to how you are expecting the result array to look like ? Because as per your code, you're output is a spot on match.

Comment: output what i expect the result is data:[100500,50000,30000,20000] etc like a row total in database, but the result just show 1 row total

Comment: Ok. thats because everytime you are executing the loop you are replacing the value of data by initializing an array.

Comment: so what should i do sir?

Comment: try the answer that I have given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$series = array('name' => 'Total Penjualan', 'data' => array());
while ($row = $penjualan->FetchNextObject(false)) {
    $result["categories"][]=$row->id_tenant;
    $result["nama_kantin"][]=$row->nama_kantin;
    array_push($series['data'], (float)$row->total);
}
$result["series"][0] = $series;
```